# httpModule does not fire when published to IIS

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, httpmodule

When I am debugging on my machine httpModule fires normally now after publishing it to IIS it does not run, what am I doing wrong? Am I missing something?

here is what it looks like in web.config

```
<httpModules>
     <add type="MyApp.Web.Mvc.Modules.Scheduler" name="Scheduler" />
</httpModules>
```

then the Scheduler looks like this

```
public class Scheduler : IHttpModule
{   
private static readonly object Job;
private static Timer timer;

static Scheduler()
{
    Job = new object();
}

void IHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication application)
{
    try
    {

        if (timer == null)
        {
            var timerCallback = new TimerCallback(ProcessJobs);
            const int startTime = 10 * 1000;
            const int timerInterval = 60 * 1000; // 1 minute
            timer = new Timer(timerCallback, null, startTime, timerInterval);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //exception code here
    } 
}

public void Dispose()
{
}

protected void ProcessJobs(object state)
{
    try
    {
        // This protects everything inside from other threads that might be invoking this
        // which is good for long running processes on the background
        lock (Job)
        {
            //My Stuff
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //exception code here
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are hosting on IIS 7.0+ integrated pipeline mode make sure that you have declared your module inside the `<system.webServer><modules>...<modules></>` section:

```
<system.webServer>
    ....
    <modules>
        <add name="Scheduler" type="MyApp.Web.Mvc.Modules.Scheduler" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

And by the way make sure you have read [The Dangers of Implementing Recurring Background Tasks in ASP.NET](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx) article by Phil Haack before putting this code in production.

Comment: Works a treat and thanks for the link I will work around it, anyways that scheduler calls a web API on another web server not on the same domain.